# Compiler picking wrong overload calling IEquatable<T>.Equals

Tags: c#, overloading, iequatable

In a performance sensitive program, I am attempting to explicitly call `IEquatable<T>.Equals()` and not `Object.Equals` (to avoid boxing in my case).  Despite my best efforts, the compiler is always choosing `Object.Equals()` instead - which I don't understand.  A contrived example class:

```
class Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IEquatable.Equals");
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object.Equals");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Equally contrived code that demonstrates the problem:

```
// This calls IEquatable<Foo>
Foo f = new Foo();
f.Equals(f);

// This calls Object.Equals
IEquatable<Foo> i = new Foo();
i.Equals(i);
```

The output of this code is:

```
IEquatable.Equals
Object.Equals
```

I read Jon Skeet's [article on overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) and came away still not understanding the problem here.  So my question is, how do I explicitly call `IEquatable<Foo>.Equals` on variable `i` above?

Comment: A `Foo` **IS** an `IEquatable<Foo>`. An `IEquatable<Foo>` **IS NOT** a `Foo`. Does that make it clearer why this works the way it does - specifcally, why `public bool Equals(Foo f)` cannot get called with a `IEquatable<Foo>`?

Comment: If you're sure that `i` *is* a `Foo`, then `i.Equals((Foo)i);`. But, of course, if you're that sure of its type, when isn't that the declared type of `i`?

Comment: On an unrelated note, can I just say what an awesome first question this is - you've given a clear statement of your problem, reproducible code, the output, a clear statement of the expected output, and finally, demonstrated independent research - have an upvote, and welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: To expand on what RB said, there are two `Equals` methods to choose from: `Equals(Foo other)` and `Equals(object obj)`. Since the given argument `i` is typed as `IEquatable<Foo>`, the object overload has to be chosen.

Comment: That is a very good comment, you should have written it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why the second overload chosen is irrelevant to the caller's type. Rather it's relevant to the type of argument you are passing to `Equals`. So even if you call `f.Equals(i)`, `object.Equals` method will be chosen. The reason is simple, compiler looks for the most appropriate overload. Since the `IEquatable<Foo>` doesn't have to be necessarily `Foo`, cause there maybe another type let's say `Bar` which implements `IEquatable<Foo>`, in that case it wouldn't be right (or possible) to choose `Equals(Foo f)` overload.

Since the compiler doesn't check the underlying type of `IEquatable<Foo>`, you need to explicitly cast the parameter to `Foo` if you want to call `Equals(Foo)` overload.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  This makes total sense and has unblocked me.